# ConstraintLayout Adding Margin to Top

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am working with an Android app that I inherited (plus I'm fairly new to Android dev) and running into a strange issue with a ConstraintLayout that is used inside a RecyclerView. Everything functions as expected, but there is a large (~15dp) gap at the top that I can't figure out how to remove, since it adds additional padding to the list that isn't necessary.

Here's the full layout - any suggestions would be much appreciated! I've played with changing the `layout_height` on the main layout, various margins/padding throughout and I can't quite get it to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txDisplayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Product Description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txSKU"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="1234567890"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txSerialNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="ABC123DEF456"/>

        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_details"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceivingSummary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLotNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="ABCD123456"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExpirationDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/prx_receiving_text_bold"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            tools:text="12/31/2024"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_delete"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/prx_divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ib_delete" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your linear layout:

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
```

Final result:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">
```

Comment: Removing layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf, is that okay?